# a php pre-defined variable to deal with multi dimensionel arrays returned from a SQL query

Tags: php

after these for example

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable")
```

i tried to echo back this

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

when i did run the query in my PHPmyadmin SQL command it came back with several lines in columns (three) from the table 
but when i echo back $row it give back just one line

```
<?php echo print_r($row); ?>
```

Comment: You might also like http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php instead of calling `mysql_fetch_array` with the assoc flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to continuously call [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) until it returns `false`, as the function returns the current row and moves the internal pointer ahead. A return value of `false` means you have iterated through all the rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    // do something with $row
}
```

Comment: if you _need_ it in an array for later use something like `array_push($rows, $row);` inside the while look